# Sample mean Margin of Error and C.I

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, z-test

I have data on the mean assembly costs for the first `n=36` days of production. It is assumed that the following data follows a Normal distribution:

```
AC <- c(345.35, 346.25, 351.65, 341.75, 347.00, 288.95, 342.50, 330.35, 326.85, 341.25,
        329.55, 327.85, 329.00, 363.50, 341.25, 329.90, 324.50, 338.90, 331.60, 333.80,
        343.45, 352.35, 351.95, 289.90, 331.75, 336.75, 341.65, 356.75, 330.95, 360.25,
        297.25, 348.95, 324.50, 338.90, 331.60, 333.80)
```

I want to do an estimation of the mean by establishing a margin of error and a confidence interval, using a 95% confidence-level.

I want to code this in R. I have already found the following statistics in R.

```
 mean(AC);
 ## [1] 335.625
 var(AC);
 ## [1] 278.8489
 sd(AC);
 ## [1] 16.69877
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you assume that your data follows a Normal distribution. We calculated the mean and standard deviation of our data, and we have `n=36` observations.

The mean of the recorded data is said to follow a [student t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with `n-1` degrees of freedom and standard deviation equal to `sd(AC) / sqrt(n)`.

If we now manage to figure out the critical t-value for a 95% confidence interval and 35 degrees of freedom, we can use the standard formula: `sample_mean` ± `critical-value`*`standard_deviation`, which is equivalent to `sample_mean`± margin_of_error`

```
n <- length(AC)

mean_X   <- mean(AC)
std_dev  <- sd(AC)/sqrt(n)
crit_val <- qt(0.975, df=35)    

margin_of_error <- std_dev * crit_val

mean_X - margin_of_error   # 329.9749
mean_X + margin_of_error   # 341.2751
```

So your 95% confidence interval is [329.97, 341.28].

Comment: Why would we not use a z test because n>30 ? Why is the CL 0.975 and not 0.95?

Comment: We use the student t-distribution, because the standard deviation `std_dev` is estimated from the data, and not the *true* standard deviation of the data generating process. The critical value for the t-distribution is a bit more conservative (i.e. larger) than the normal (z) distribution. We use CL 0.975 because the 95% confidence interval is two-sided: A statistic can be outside the CI by being too small, but also by being too large. Therefore the remaining 5% is split. If you use 0.95, you'd end up with a 90% CI

Comment: If you really want to use the critical value of the normal distribution, you could use `crit_val <- qnorm(0.975)`. It's not something I would recommend, though